# console error using requiredfieldvalidator

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I am getting this error in the console for my web pages.

```
GET http://localhost:49767/EnerTeckWebsite_December2012/(S(v1qkix21cbp21r2qbuzlp1hv))/Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.js 404 (Not Found)
```

What is strange is, a) im using the google CDN for my jquery and I have 1.8.2 in my scripts folder not 1.8.1. So I removed everything from the page and one by one added things back.
The asp:RequiredFieldValidator is what is causing this error in the console. Is that control asking for jquery 1.8.1?

The markup im using is below

```
<div id="addnewcontact" class="visible">
    <fieldset style="width:70%;">
        <legend>Add New Contact Form</legend>
        <asp:panel runat="server" ID="custform" cssclass="contactform">
        <%--FirstName--%>
            <asp:Label ID="lblFirstname"  AssociatedControlID="firstname" Text="First Name:" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="firstname"  runat="server" CssClass="textboxes placeholder" Text=""
                         TabIndex="1" Tooltip="Enter your first name here" Width="250" BackColor="#CCFFCC"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFirstName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="[Required]"
                            ControlToValidate="firstname" CssClass="validation-summary-errors">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>&nbsp;&nbsp;


            <br /><p class="spacer"></p>
            <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="buttons" />
        </asp:panel> <%--end of custform panel--%>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Can anyone explain why a) its looking for a jquery version Im not even referencing and b) is there something peculiar in how the RequriedFieldValidator works?

Here is the rendered html, somehow a script reference is getting in there to 1.8.1

```
<script src="/EnerTeckWebsite_December2012/WebResource.axd?d=pynGkmcFUV13He1Qd6_TZEhw5ogJwHMaGvv1faj0ohidrhqfoYJwjxtK8gBUdHUYC2f9QooQdJrQd8gPrks-mg2&amp;t=634773918900000000" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/EnerTeckWebsite_December2012/Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/EnerTeckWebsite_December2012/WebResource.axd?d=x2nkrMJGXkMELz33nwnakJlfi53iisy1dQO0tCbSRSWSLiZnFT5LN-XRQqeUoK_7idgcf-wX-V5IQv2Vbycn_GyYa4xZktCNxaI6T1wfZgA1&amp;t=634773918900000000" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but the Google CDN is already calling jquery much earlier in the page.

EDIT: I removed the update panels and scriptmanager. They are not calling for 1.8.1 as that tag isnt on the page and there is not error when requiredfieldvalidator is set to false BUT when I set it back to true the error is there. Somehow that control is specifically asking for 1.8.1 is this an AJAX issue? any help would be appreciated.

Thought? Is a regularexpresssionvalidator even necessary anymore with html5 textboxes where you can set the type, ie type=email

Comment: are you using a script manager to insert the plugin file? If so it sounds like you need to modify settings to not include jQUery in page again

Comment: there is a script manager in the master page but I am not loading any jquery files using a script manager for this page. In fact i dont even have any scripts on this page at all yet.

Comment: there error disappears if i set enableclientscript to false in both the regularexpressionvalidator and the requiredfieldvalidator. is this indicative of a problem in AJAX? Will the false setting become problematic if a utilize scripts on this page?

Comment: I don't use asp or(or dotNet) tenough to know how to set script manager. But look in page source. Manager is adding a script tag for `jquery-1.8.1` if you aren't adding it yourself. Should be easy to research as an asp issue. Add aprporiate tags to this question... is not a jQuery issue at all

Answer (score 0):

Can you comment out everything on that page and load it up. If the 1.8.1 reference is still there I bet it's from the `MasterPage` instead of any child controls on that page.

Comment: did that. It is most certainly coming from the RequiredFieldValidator